# Entity Framework core configurations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In EF 6 we could directly pass EntityTypeConfiguration to model builder to build maps and keep our configuration class separate from context without being too verbose in code.

Have they removed those maps in EF core. Is there a way to add configuration without doing it in model builder for every class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way is to keep the configuration code away from the `OnModelCreating` method. So you can do something like:

Create a class where you will store the actual configuration:

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration
{
    public ApplicationUserConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> entity)
    {
        // Here you have all the good stuff
        entity.ToTable("user", "identity");

        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id);

        // And so on ....
    }
}
```

And into your `OnModelCreating` instantiate the new created class and pass the correct entity:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Your custom configs here
    new ApplicationUserConfiguration(builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>());
}
```

Is clean and a simple way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Did something similar to that... Instead of a different class I created a static method Configure () for each class and passed the builder

Comment: @Jajan that was also my first thought / attempt. But i'd wanted to avoid unnecessary References to EntityFramework since i wanted my "Entities" to be reused across Projects and Platforms. Just my my 2 ct ;). Your Solution works as well as any other and there ist nothing wrong about it.

Answer (score 21):

EntityFrameworkCore2.0 has a [`IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/#self-contained-type-configuration-for-code-first) which can be used as:

```
class ApplicationUserMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable("user", "identity");

    builder.Property(p => p.Id)
        .HasColumnName("id");
     ...
   }
}

...
// OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserMap());
```

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a way to add configuration without doing it in model builder
>   for every class?

It definitely is a lot of extra work if you have hundred of tables in database, and you have to configure each and every mapping class manually.

With the help of [this extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2805), you can achieve the desired result in few line of codes like good old EF 6.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Type[] types = typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes();
    IEnumerable<Type> typesToRegister = types
        .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace) &&
                        type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType != null &&
                        type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType &&
                        type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

    foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
    {
        dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        ModelBuilderExtensions.AddConfiguration(modelBuilder, configurationInstance);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

### Extension Method

```
public abstract class EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public abstract void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder);
}

public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AddConfiguration<TEntity>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> configuration)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        configuration.Map(modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>());
    }
}
```

### Mapping Class

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        ...
    } 
}
```