# Where are Entity Framework Core conventions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

using EF 6.1+ there were times where we need to add or remove existing conentions. The code looks more or less like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
}
```

how do the same in EF core? Modelbuilder has no Conventions property :(

Comment: *Where are Entity Framework Core conventions?* Somewhere in the future (check EF Core roadmap and backlog).

Comment: It's planned for the 3.0 release, see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/214

Comment: For .NET Core 3.1 --

[Answer-One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493095/entity-framework-core-rc2-table-name-pluralization#answer-57670401)

[Answer-Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493095/entity-framework-core-rc2-table-name-pluralization#answer-37502978)

Comment: For EF Core 5 and singular over plural table name convention see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585664/1769622

Answer (score 19):

I'm porting some code from EF to EF Core 2.1+ and can't wait for EF Core 3.0 so wrote a few extension methods which help a bit..

```
public static IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> EntityTypes(this ModelBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.Model.GetEntityTypes();
}

public static IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> Properties(this ModelBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.EntityTypes().SelectMany(entityType => entityType.GetProperties());
}

public static IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> Properties<T>(this ModelBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.EntityTypes().SelectMany(entityType => entityType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.ClrType == typeof(T)));
}

public static void Configure(this IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> entityTypes, Action<IMutableEntityType> convention)
{
    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        convention(entityType);
    }
}

public static void Configure(this IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> propertyTypes, Action<IMutableProperty> convention)
{
    foreach (var propertyType in propertyTypes)
    {
        convention(propertyType);
    }
}
```

with these you can write conventions similar to those in EF 6.1.x, for example.

```
// equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
modelBuilder.EntityTypes()
            .Configure(et => et.Relational().TableName = et.DisplayName());

// Put the table name on the primary key
modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Id")
            .Configure(p => p.Relational().ColumnName = p.DeclaringEntityType.Name + "Id");

// Mark timestamp columns as concurrency tokens
modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Timestamp")
            .Configure(p => p.IsConcurrencyToken = true);
```

For EF Core 3.0 the metamodel methods have changed slightly so you need

```
modelBuilder.EntityTypes()
            .Configure(et => et.SetTableName(et.DisplayName()));

modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Id")
            .Configure(p => p.SetColumnName(BaseName(p.DeclaringEntityType.Name) + "Id"));
```

Haven't checked this for efficiency but unless your model is huge it shouldn't pose a problem

This can be extended with other helpers for foreign keys, indexes etc

Comment: Is it there in .net core 3.1??

Answer (score 13):

Looks like it's still not in EF Core 2.0. So here's one way of achieving it. I had done this to apply consistent behaviour to certain attributes, but to address the examples in your question you could try this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    // look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43075152/3419825

    // for the other conventions, we do a metadata model loop
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.DisplayName();

        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        // and modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        entityType.GetForeignKeys()
            .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(fk => fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

You should be able to do a lot of things with `entityType`

Comment: entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.DisplayName(); can be dangerous if entityType is an 'owned' type. DisplayName() returns the owner table name if entityType is an 'owned' type. This is gonna mess up the database design resp. the migration script.

Comment: @thomasgalliker Got a solution?

Comment: Meanwhile, I just filter of types which are IsOwned() == true. Have a look at this line of code: https://github.com/thomasgalliker/EntityFramework.Toolkit.EFCore/blob/12d79c17af26dfd80dc5a13c018ff615c08f2ab8/EFCore.Toolkit/Extensions/ModelBuilderExtensions.cs#L24

Answer (score 1):

In order to set singular table names in EF Core 5 you can do the following

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()            
    .Configure(et => et.SetTableName(et.DisplayName()));
```

but then if you have value objects in you domain they will all be treated as entity types and created as tables in the database. If your value objects all inherit from a base type like `ValueObject` you can use the following:

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()            
    .Where(x => !x.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject)))
    .Configure(et => et.SetTableName(et.DisplayName()));
```

Another drawback in EF Core 5 is that when you use inheritance in your entity model, setting tables names changes from [Table-per-Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) (TPH) to [Table-per-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration) (TPT)

You could use the following alternative (assuming your entities derive from `BaseEntity`)

```
modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(x => x.ClrType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
    .Configure(et => et.SetTableName(et.DisplayName()));
```

where Configure is defined as an extension method:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> EntityTypes(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.Model.GetEntityTypes();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> Properties(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.EntityTypes().SelectMany(entityType => entityType.GetProperties());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> Properties<T>(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.EntityTypes().SelectMany(entityType => entityType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.ClrType == typeof(T)));
    }

    public static void Configure(this IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> entityTypes, Action<IMutableEntityType> convention)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            convention(entityType);
        }
    }

    public static void Configure(this IEnumerable<IMutableProperty> propertyTypes, Action<IMutableProperty> convention)
    {
        foreach (var propertyType in propertyTypes)
        {
            convention(propertyType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting `'IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType>' does not contain a definition for 'Configure'` when I try to do this.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum Sorry, I have missed that. Answer updated. Added extension methods for ModelBuilder